# make width the same size as another html element

Tags: html, css, hover

Hi I have a dropdown button that when you hover it, it drops down some links to pages. I want those links to be the same size as the width of the button.

The button size is 100% width of the content, so it varies. How do I make the size of the drop down items the same size as the button with CSS?

```
    <style type="text/css">
      #button {  /* Box in the button */
        display: block;
        width: 190px;
      }

      #button a {
        text-decoration: none;  /* Remove the underline from the links. */
      }
ul
{
list-style-type:none;
margin:0;
padding:0;
overflow:hidden;
}
li{
float:left;
list-style-type: none;
}
      #button ul {
        list-style-type: none;  /* Remove the bullets from the list */
      }

      #button .top {
display:block;
width:100%;
font-weight:bold;
color:#FFFFFF;
background-color:#98bf21;
text-align:center;
padding:4px;
text-decoration:none;
text-transform:uppercase;  /* The button background */
      }

      #button ul li.item {
        display: none;  /* By default, do not display the items (which contains the links) */
      }  

      #button ul:hover .item {  /* When the user hovers over the button (or any of the links) */
        display: block;

        border: 1px solid black;
        background-color: #6CC417;
      }
a:link,a:visited
{
display:block;
width:120px;
font-weight:bold;
color:#FFFFFF;
background-color:#98bf21;
text-align:center;
padding:4px;
text-decoration:none;
text-transform:uppercase;
}
a:hover,a:active
{
background-color:#7A991A;


}
.container
{
text-align:center;
}

.center_div
{
border:1px solid gray;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
width:90%;
background-color:#d0f0f6;
text-align:left;
padding:8px;
}

    </style>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF">

<p><img src="Screen%20shot%202010-07-11%20at%204.07.59%20PM.png" width="211" height="86" alt="idc"> 

<ul>
<li>
    <div id="button">
      <ul>
        <li class="top">OtherOverflow Sites</li>
        <li class="item"><a href="http://serverfault.com/">Visit serverfault</a></li>
        <li class="item"><a href="http://superuser.com/">Visit superuser</a></li>
        <li class="item"><a href="http://doctype.com/">Visit doctype</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
</li>
<li>
    <div id="button">
      <ul>
        <li class="top">OtherOverflow Sites</li>
        <li class="item"><a href="http://serverfault.com/">Visit serverfault</a></li>
        <li class="item"><a href="http://superuser.com/">Visit superuser</a></li>
        <li class="item"><a href="http://doctype.com/">Visit doctype</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
</li>
</ul></p>
<div class="container">
<div class="center_div">
<h1>Hello World!</h1>
<p>This example contains some advanced CSS methods you may not have learned yet. But, we will explain these methods in a later chapter in the tutorial.</p>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Three things:

1. `#button ul:hover .item` needs width set to 100%.

   ```
     #button ul:hover .item {any of the links) */
       display: block;
       width:100%;
       border: 1px solid black;
       background-color: #6CC417;
     }
   ```

   .
2. All links are set to 120px!

   ```
   a:link,a:visited {
     display:block;
     width:120px;
     ...
   ```

   Delete the `width:120px;`
3. As meder said, Do not use an id, use a class.  And the code has the same id multiple times -- which is illegal.

   So: `<div id="button">` becomes: `<div class="DropDwnMenuBtn">`.

Answer (score 1):

1. You have multiple button ids. Use classes for multiple elements.
2. Shouldn't you just need #button a { display:block; }? It's hard to tell when you don't have a visual.